# setting row height not to go below bottom of page bootstrap

Tags: angular, layout, bootstrap-4, angular-material2

I'm trying to make a sidenav that will scale it's size based on window size.

I'm giving it a list of items, which combined are taller than the window height. I want to make it a scrollable list, without setting max-height, but instead have it always be the window height.

this is how it currently looks:

[image: bug]

you can see that the window is scrolled down, and the sidenav scroll is disabled. I've tried many things, currently this is the state of my code:

#### logs.component.html

```
<div class="container" [style.max-height]="containerHeight()" (window:resize)="resize($event.target.innerHeight)">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2" color="primary">
      <app-search-sidebar (selectedChanged)="selected=$event" [items]="items"></app-search-sidebar>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <md-tab-group>
        <md-tab [label]="selected">
          <h1>{{selected}}</h1>
          <p>...</p>
        </md-tab>
      </md-tab-group>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### logs.component.css

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -9999px;
    padding-bottom: 9999px;
}

.row > div {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

#### logs.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProcessesList } from './mock_data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-logs',
  templateUrl: './logs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logs.component.css']
})
export class LogsComponent {

  items: string[] = ProcessesList;
  selected: string = '';
  height: number;


  containerHeight(): number {
    return this.height <= 0 ? window.innerHeight : this.height;
  }

  resize(height: number) {
    this.height = height;
  }
}
```

this is a rather weird attempt, but it still doesn't help.

the inner component:

#### search-sidebar.component.html

```
<div>
  <label class="sr-only" for="processName">Process Name</label>
  <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <md-icon>search</md-icon>
    </div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" class="form-control" id="processName" placeholder="Process Name">
  </div>
  <div class="process-list">
    <md-list>
      <md-list-item *ngFor="let item of items | listFilter:searchValue">
        <button md-raised-button [color]="isSelected(item) ? 'primary' : ''"
                class="process-name" (click)="changeSelected(item)">
          {{item}}
        </button>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### search-sidebar.component.css

```
.process-name {
    width: 100%;
}

.process-list {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

#### search-sidebar.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './search-sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SearchSidebarComponent {
  @Input() public items: string[] = [];
  @Output() selectedChanged: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  private _selected: string = '';
  private searchValue: string;

  changeSearch(search: string) {
    this.searchValue = search;
  }

  isSelected(item: string) {
    return this.selected === item;
  }

  changeSelected(selected: string) {
    if (this.selected !== selected) {
      this.selected = selected;
    }
  }

  get selected() {
    return this._selected;
  }
  set selected(selected: string) {
    this._selected = selected;
    this.selectedChanged.emit(this.selected);
  }
}
```

I'm using Angular Material 2 where I can, otherwise pure Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can all be accomplished through CSS and using flex!

working example: http://embed.plnkr.co/5NsImxRJc5dvddfnr6s6/

The trick is to set the height of HTML and BODY to 100%, as well as all the parent DIVs to the container DIV.  Then set the container DIV to "display: flex; overflow-y: auto".

Very rarely should you put layout code in your angular classes.

Comment: What I did fail to mention is that I also have a toolbar in the top which does take a bit of height from the top, and although I havent yet checked, it's likely that when I use 100% height on the container, it overflows by the height of the toolbar. Any idea on how to accomandate for a toolbar? Maybe do a `top: -TOOLBAR-HEIGHTpx` trick or something?

Comment: I've managed to limit the component's containing div height using `calc(100% - 64px)`, but now, the inner component doesn't scale based on it's containing div (inner div height is larger than it's containing div height). This is the new post i've opened, in case you'd wanna help: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41563621/limiting-size-of-component-to-containing-divs-height`

Comment: No need to use calc or specify heights in pixels - each div can size itself.  The trick is to just use another flex (vertical one this time) on the container, and put the toolbar and log panel inside of that:

`.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.logpanel {
  display: flex;
}`

Updated example: http://plnkr.co/edit/5NsImxRJc5dvddfnr6s6?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The answer was using `calc` in the css, since the toolbar also had some height.

In the end, that's the css:

#### logs.component.css

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.row > .col* {
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: calc(100% - 64px);
    max-height: calc(100% - 64px);
}

app-search-sidebar {
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar-container {
  min-width: 300px;
  /*max-width: 300px;*/
}
```